# Using a cell reference, instead of a URL address in IMPORTRANGE function

Tags: url, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have several sheets which use the ImportRange Function.  Every month, we need to change the URL to pull the data from another sheet.  I was hoping to have one cell where we can enter what sheet we wish use to do all the ImportRange Functions vs manually going into each sheet and updating the URL monthly.  Hope this makes sense, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if you want cell with url/id use:

```
=IMPORTRANGE(A1, "Sheet1!A:C")
```

if you want cell with sheet too try:

```
=IMPORTRANGE(A1, B1)
```

Comment: Thank you, however if the web address on on another worksheet, how would I reference this please?

Comment: @Smgrant4 hard to tell what is your exact setup but try: `=IMPORTRANGE(IMPORTRANGE("url", "Sheet1!A1"), B1)`